# Insert all value of Array in new row - App Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I'm new in Google App script and I'm trying to insert all value of array in new row and this is my code,

```
  var lttr = ["a", "b", "c"];
  for (var i=0; i < lttr.length; i++) {
  sheet.getRange(range+1, 1).setValue(lttr);
  }
```

It only insert the value

```
"a"
```

Not this one

```
a
b
c
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following code:

```
function insertValues() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var lttr = [ [ "a" , "b" , "c" ] ];
  var rowNumber = 1;
  var ColumnNumber = 1;
  sheet.getRange(rowNumber,ColumnNumber,lttr.length,lttr[0].length).setValues(lttr);
};
```

Edit:

If you want to insert the values in a column (that is in rows) then try the following code:

```
function insertValues() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var lttr = [ [ "a" ] , [ "b" ] , [ "c" ] ];
  var rowNumber = 1;
  var ColumnNumber = 1;
  sheet.getRange(rowNumber,ColumnNumber,lttr.length,lttr[0].length).setValues(lttr);
};
```

Comment: Hi @kishan, thank for the help my problem is i want to put the value of array into next row, like the value will going to put into cell
A:1 = 'a' , A:2 = 'b' A:3 = 'c'

Comment: Yeah it Works, thanks @kishan i vote your answer, thanks again +1

Answer (score 0):

Instead of looping over your array, simply select the entire range and use the setValues() function rather than setValue().

See:
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setValues(Object)

Comment: i try it, but it only inset into column not into next row of it